# Where to find Eucalyptus API?

Tags: api, cloud, eucalyptus

Does it possible to access Eucalyptus buckets by using API ? if yes where to find Eucalyptus API?. I searched a lot for it but I could not find any. 
The Eucalyptus [website](http://www.eucalyptus.cloud) mention APIs but there is no link.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Eucalyptus re-implements the APIs of AWS EC2 (Elastic Compute Cloud), S3 (Simple Storage Service), EBS (Elastic Block Store), ELB (Elastic Load Balancer), IAM (Identity and Access Management) and CloudWatch (Monitoring). The  documentation of these APIs can be found on the web pages of the AWS. You search for the EBS API. It is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/OperationList-query-ebs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Eucalyptus is  (AWS)-compatible private and hybrid cloud computing environments .
So you will not able to find the Public API